# ajax calls getting hang in case of implementing synchrous plus asynchronous

Tags: javascript, jquery, yui

I have set of Ajax calls. And those calls has to be called group by.
For ex: 
I Need to call Ajax calls  in following manner.

```
var ajaxCallListGroupBy = [["AjxStep_11", "AjxStep_12", "AjxStep_13"],["AjxStep_21", "AjxStep_22", "AjxStep_23"]];
```

Once first index of array Ajax calls finished, we need to call second index of array Ajax calls.

So, i was using below machanism to call ajax calls. But, page is getting hanged.

```
function callGroupByAjaxCalls(newIndex){
        orderOneAjaxCount = 0;
        var listOfQueries = ajaxCallListGroupBy[newIndex];
        groupCalls = listOfQueries.length;
        for (var currIndex=0,len=listOfQueries.length; currIndex<len; currIndex++){ 
            window[listOfQueries[currIndex]]();
        }

        if(ajaxCallListGroupBy.length>1){//To check how many times we have to iterate
            if(newIndex < (ajaxCallListGroupBy.length-1) && (orderOneAjaxCount >= ajaxCallListGroupBy[newIndex].length)){
                callGroupByAjaxCalls(newIndex+1);
            }else{
                console.log("After 3 secs orderOneAjaxCount "+orderOneAjaxCount);
                setTimeout(plsWait(newIndex),1000);
                if(plsWait(newIndex)){
                    callGroupByAjaxCalls(index+1);
                }
            }
        }else if(ajaxCallListGroupBy.length <= newIndex){//To check index already reached to actual calls
            console.log("no need of further calls. Alreay all ajax calls hit from APP");
        }else if(ajaxCallListGroupBy.length == newIndex){ //If there is only one set of ajax calls there
            console.log("only one set of ajax calls. So no need to call any other ajax call");
        }else{
            console.log("handle new use case");
        }
}

function plsWait(index){
        var flg = true;
        console.log("orderOneAjaxCount = "+orderOneAjaxCount+" ajaxCallListGroupBy[index].length ="+ajaxCallListGroupBy[index].length);
        if(!(orderOneAjaxCount >= ajaxCallListGroupBy[index].length)){
            for(l=0;l<20000;l++){

            }
            if(!(orderOneAjaxCount >= ajaxCallListGroupBy[index].length)){
                plsWait(index);
            }
        }
        return flg;
}
```

Note: `orderOneAjaxCount` will be incremented at each ajax call.

Comment: unable to format. Till Note, every thing is javascript code only

Comment: what do you think,where may be the problem?

Comment: Do you realize that `setTimeout(plsWait(newIndex),1000);` is NOT waiting before calling `plsWait()`.  It's being called immediately.  You have to pass a function reference (a function name without parens).

Comment: jfriend00.. you mean to say we shouldn't pass function with parameters in setTimeout method?

Comment: you could wrap the plsWait(newIndex) call in a closure.  i.e. setTimeout(function(){plsWait(newIndex)},1000);

Answer (score 0):

If you're using YUI, I'd recommend that you look at `Y.io.queue`. It should help you schedule those requests correctly. See: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/io/#queue